# Cors Error once deployed Angular and SpringBoot App in Heroku

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, xmlhttprequest, cors

im going through really hard times with this app cause of cors.
In local work perfect , but once deployed the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://portafolioback.herokuapp.com/portafolio/version1/post/all' from origin 'https://frontportafolio.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Both part of the app(Front (Angular) and Back(Spring-Boot)) are already deployed in heroku, and my
configuration for the front end in the controller is like this

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const mongoUrl ='https://portafolioback.herokuapp.com/portafolio/version1/';

const myMail = 'https://mailthis.to/cubancoder@gmail.com';
let headersReq = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
});

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PostServicesService {
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ...some code.....
  getAllPosts() {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${mongoUrl}post/all`, { headers: headersReq });
  }
}
```

And in my back the controller would look like this :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://frontportafolio.herokuapp.com", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("portafolio/version1")
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @GetMapping("/post/all")
    public List<Post> getAllPost(){
        return postRepository.findAllComments();
    }
}
```

Then as this configuration of CrossOrigin was also useless , i added in my Application file a cors global configuration like this :

```
package com.portafolio.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
 class WebConfig implements Filter,WebMvcConfigurer {



    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        System.out.println("WebConfig; "+request.getRequestURI());
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://frontportafolio.herokuapp.com");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,observe");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "responseType");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "observe");
        System.out.println("Request Method: "+request.getMethod());
        if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
            try {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pre-flight");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"+"Authorization, content-type," +
                    "USERID"+"ROLE"+
                    "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with,responseType,observe");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }

    }

}
```

But still keep having the same error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://portafolioback.herokuapp.com/portafolio/version1/post/all' from origin 'https://frontportafolio.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Please ...any help with this situation would be amazing!!.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to allow the credentials  **or**

I faced this same issue when i worked on it.Heroku will only install packeges from your dependancies
And what I needed was in my devDependencies,so once I reinstalled as dependancies it worked!

Add this code to **serve.js**
**like :**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});
```

try to add `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` at **service** file

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const mongoUrl 
  ='https://portafolioback.herokuapp.com/portafolio/version1/';
    

const myMail = 'https://mailthis.to/cubancoder@gmail.com';
let headersReq = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PostServicesService {
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ...some code.....
  getAllPosts() {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${mongoUrl}post/all`, { headers: headersReq });
  }
}
```

Comment: could you expplaiin my on detail ...or could you suggest me a documentation to remit at...thanks Dako

Comment: this code you sent looks like pure node express back-end one

Comment: this app is built in angular and spring boot

Comment: Sadly keeps the same

Comment: try to add this chrome extenstion 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Comment: when i test the extensioin in my app it says  :CORS is blocked by GET